# onsen-ui で angular-translate を利用したい

Tags: onsen-ui, angularjs, cordova

お世話になります。
Cordova + onsen-ui + angular-js でアプリケーションを開発しています。
国際化対応のため、こちらのサイト(http://qiita.com/ukiuni@github/items/1d1b47e274ac204709c9) を参考に angular-translate を入れ込んだところ、以下のエラーメッセージが表示されてしまいます。

> Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [onsButton, translate] asking for new/isolated

(ボタンに表示させるメッセージとして設定しています。)
'translate' が競合しているらしいという所までは把握できていますが、どのように解決したらいいかがわからない状態です。
解決方法について、ご教示頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: 改めて確認しましたところ、<ons-button> タグ内に 'translate' を指定した場合に上記エラーメッセージが表示される事が確認できました。
通常の HTML タグに指定した場合は正しく変換されていましたので、アプローチを変えて対応していきたいと思います。

お騒がせ致しました。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決したようですが、私も同じようなことをしていますので一応書いておきます。
下のように、ons-button内のspanなどhtmlの標準のタグの中でangular-translateを使うとうまくいくと思います。

```
   <ons-button modifier="large">
        <span translate="TEXT_ID"></span>
   </ons-button>
```

これ以外でも、他のプラグインなどの機能をonsen-UIの独自タグの中でやろうとしてダメな時は、このような感じでやるとうまくいくことが多いです。（まぁ、それ用に作っているわけではないので当たり前ですが）

Comment: _これ以外でも、他のプラグインなどの機能をonsen-UIの独自タグの中でやろうとしてダメな時は、このような感じでやるとうまくいくことが多いです。（まぁ、それ用に作っているわけではないので当たり前ですが）_

確かにそうですね。
同様のケースになった場合は、このような形で対応してみたいと思います。